# Fixed tabs in new material design android

Tags: android, tabs, material-design, toolbar

I've searched stackoverflow and google material design documentation quite a lot but can't find a way how to correctly implement simple fixed tabs in the new material design. I am using appcompat v7 library with toolbar which is great but can't seem to find a way to add tabs to it or simply below it as it is shown here[image: tabs from google website]

I've found the [SlidingTabsBasic](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/project.html) class but that does not meet my requirements as I only use 2 tabs, and they don't fill in the whole horizontal space

Could you please point me into right direction on how to implement those (maybe I have only misunderstood how google wants us to use/implement them).

Much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually google has not released anything, but my custom library uses the style and animation defined in the `Material Design` guidelines.

[Here](https://github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs) you can find it, good work!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can see you've just added new features to your library to match my demands as well. Hope this will help out not only me but others as well.

Comment: I hope so. Another thing, remember that the material tabs and the toolbar are now different. So you have to insert it below your toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Google has released a [Material Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html), which includes a `TabLayout` to create Material design easier